# WPF/MVVM - binding collection of child controls

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

some advice from he WPF/MVVM gurus, pls.

I come from a Windows Forms background and I am porting a personal project from VB.NET to WPF. I  started with a straight re-write with the logic going in the code-behind files, albeit with a discrete Data Access Layer.However then I discovered MVVM and that I was 'doing it all wrong' and should be abstracting the logic into a View Model accessing a data model. I think I've absorbed the new paradigm and my code behind files are now  (nearly) empty.

(As an aside, I buy into the rationale behind MVVM, but I'm not sure about the 'easier to test and debug' argument, due to all the 'plumbing' of routed events and commands etc, I appreciate the need but it seems to me sometimes to obscure rather than clarify what is going on. But I a very much a novice, maybe it will come with practice.)

Anyhow - here's what has got me scratching my head; the app is a dive planning/recording tool for scuba diving centres. Logically, its like a calendar or diary app, with the need to record the time and site of each dive and who went on each dive. The main screen resembles one page of a diary and I have a user control that encapsulates the dive info. On change of selected date, the diary page is cleared and re-populated with the dives for the new selected date. The View Model retrieves and exposes a list of 'Dive' objects (classes) for the new date. The container is a Stackpanel and I want to clear its children and then create and add the new Dive user controls to the child controls collection.

My question is - where is the appropriate place to do this - View code behind or View Model? The former is relatively easy but seems to me to break the pattern, but I am stumped by how I would achieve it in the view model. The sequence needs to be

- User selects a new date (calendar control)
- Handle  the selected date change event
- Clear Stackpanel child controls
- Retrieve list of dives for new date from db and generate a user control for each
- Add user controls as stackpanel child controls.

I guess what I'm asking is - is there a way of binding the collection of child controls to a collection of objects in the view model such that it responds dynamically - and is this a sensible approach?

Comment: Your list at the bottom is 100% winforms and 0% mvvm.  You might want to spin up a couple prototypes where you do very trivial MVVM work before attempting a rewrite, as a way of learning how different tasks are accomplished.  If you don't understand how mvvm works in wpf, don't try to learn it while you're in production code.

Comment: Thanks Will, I did concede that I am a MVVM novice, and I have already developed some 'toy' apps. Still getting my head around the power of binding..

Comment: More toy apps!  I've saved all of mine.  Have hundreds of them in different subjects.  It's a great way to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate way to do this would be to wrap your `StackPanel` in an `ItemsControl` and bind the `ItemsSource` to your `Dives` of the selected day. When your `DivesOfThatDay` is changed (make sure to implement INotifyChanged or a DependencyProperty, or use an ObservableCollection), every single entry will be generated automatically.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DivesOfThatDay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Dive}">
            <!-- Your Template -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In MVVM you should always avoid generating Controls in Code-Behind. Your View should take the Data from your ViewModel and do that on its own - otherwise MVVM would be kind of useless. In your case it should work like this:

1. User selects a new date in the **view**
2. Because the date control in the **view** is bound to some property in your **viewmodel**, that property gets updated.
3. The **viewmodel** reacts to this change by clearing its current collection of dives and fetching a new one.
4. The **model** data (from the database) gets encapsulated in a **viewmodel** (a `Dive`) and added to the dive collection in the **viewmodel**
5. The **view** (`ItemsControl`) gets notified of this change (via `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` or whatever) and tells its `ItemContainerGenerator` to update the controls.
6. The ItemsContainerGenerator generates a **view** for every `Dive` in your **viewmodel** and adds it to the stackpanel.

Or in short V → VM → M → VM → V

Comment: I'd have suggested that he make `Dives` an `ObservableCollection`, raise `PropertyChanged` on a new collection instance, and never mind the other approaches. Can't go wrong with that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett *"Can't"* might be a bit of an exaggeration. I've seen plenty of people using `dataThatDoesntUpdate = new ObservableCollection ...` and wondering what they did wrong. But I agree - an `ObservableCollection` or any other class implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` would suit this situation well. His basic approach `Retrieve list of dives for new date from db and generate a user control for each` should absolutely not be done manually.

Comment: True, there's nothing that can't *ever* be done wrong. Entirely in agreement about ItemsControl+DataTemplate for creating the controls.

Comment: If you are altering the collection, use an ObservableCollection.  If you're simply replacing the collection, just use an INPC IEnumerable property.  Doing both is... kinda goofy.  If I've got an OC property, it's read only, and doesn't implement property change notification.

Comment: Brilliant Manfred. That sounds spot on. I'll give it a try.

Thanks for pushing me a little further up the learning curve.

Comment: Manfred: Please how would you add scrolling bar there? It announces me error when i try to wrap StackPanel with ScrollViewer. :-(